# User-defined keyboard shortcut on highlighted text in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I need to create a shortcut that does the following:

I want to highlight text (say TEXT is highlighted) in the editor in vscode, and on triggering a keyboard shortcut, I need to replace it with say [\something TEXT]. How can I do this?

I tried adding the following to keybindings.json, of course, this does not work:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "command": "type",
    "args":{
    "text":"{\\color{red}%TEXT%}"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `editorHasSelection` than `editorTextFocus` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it a keybinding that inserts a snippet.  Then you can use variables like `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT`.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+r",
   "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "{\\color{red}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Select your text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or double-click it) and then trigger the keybinding above.

You could use the command `type` but you need to use it twice in a macro: once before the keyword and once after, so it is easier to just use the `insertSnippet` version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "regexTextGen.generateText",
    "args": {
      "generatorRegex" : "\\{\\color\\{red\\}{{0}}\\}",
    }
  }
```