# VS Code/R - how to paste highlighted text in editor to arguments in keyboard shortcut

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am regularly using the `skimr::skim(name_of_a_dataframe)` command in r when working interactively. To make the work a bit more efficient, I would like to assign the command to a keyboard shortcut which applies `skimr::skim()` to the text highlighted in the editor, i.e. the name of the dataframe. Essentially, the behavior should be similar to the keybinding F2 which opens the dataframe.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
{
  "key": "F7",
  "description": "run skimr::skim() on df",
  "command": "r.runCommand",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": "skimr::skim(XXXX)"
}
```

The problem I am facing is this: How can I insert the text which I highlighted/selected in the editor paste into the args section of the keybinding (XXXX).

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604805/user-defined-keyboard-shortcut-on-highlighted-text-in-vscode) on SO, but the solution is eventually a snippet, something I do not need. Many thanks.

Comment: in VSC you have to do it with a snippet

Comment: @rioV8 many thanks for the comment. but isn't a snippet's purpose to insert predefined text into the editor? My motivation is exactly to avoid this. I just want to press the key and trigger the command. No inserting of additional text/commands into the editor.

Comment: the accepted answer executes the snippet with a key binding, select text and press key binding

Comment: I tried this solution, but it inserts the result, the modified text, into the editor. What I am looking for is that the command is triggered and I get the result in the console (the description of the dataframe as provided by skimr::skim()). There should be no change to the text of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `r.runCommandWithSelectionOrWord` and represent the selection or word under the cursor with `$$`:

```json
{
  "key": "F7",
  "description": "run skimr::skim() on df",
  "command": "r.runCommandWithSelectionOrWord",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": "skimr::skim($$)"
}
```

Info about this and related commands is on the vscode-R Wiki here: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Keyboard-shortcuts#creating-keybindings-for-r-commands